# VirtualBox, client can't connect to Windows server 2008 (2 NIC's)

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, virtualhost, virtual-machines, rras

I have a virutal environment as follows:

- a `Windows server 2008` with two `NIC's`. One `NIC` is connected to internel 'LAN' and the other to 'LAN2'. Roles: `DHCP`, `AD`, `DNS` and `RRAS`.
- a `Windows 7` client. The `NIC` is connected to 'LAN2'.

Almost everything is out of the box, I only set up two `DHCP` pools.

The problem is that the client can't obtain a `IP` of the `DHCP` server. The server also can't be pinged with a static ip.. (the connections details shows incomming packets)

But when I change the network of the client to "LAN", then I get a IP from the `DHCP` without problems.

How does this come?

Comment: What pools do you have configured on your DHCP server?

Comment: Pool 1: 192.168.0.1 /24, Pool 2: 10.0.0.1 /24

Comment: And the Bindings are OK? DHCP is listening on both NICs? `netstat -an`

Comment: A lot of data is flying through the console. For what kind of data must I look for?

Comment: You're looking to see if the DHCP service is listening on all IP addresses bound to the server. DHCP listens on UDP 67 so perhaps a better command to run would be `netstat -an -p UDP` and look for an entry listing port 67 next to it. Better still, provide us with the entire list.

Comment: I'm unable to post the list at this moment. But the IP 192.168.0.10 and 10.0.0.10 (the DHCP server ip) is listening on 67 UDP.

Answer (score -1):

DHCP requests are ICMP broadcasts. And broadcasts are not routed to WAN by design. I could have lookup the RFC, but it is a fact.

ICMP broadcasts are only valid in local LAN and so it can only work inside the LAN.

Comment: I only named the virtual network "WAN". I could name it whatever i wanted. So it can be handled as a LAN.

Comment: So what are your IPs and netmasks on each of the server's NIC?

Comment: LAN: 192.168.0.1 /24 and on LAN2: 10.0.0.1 /24

Comment: Looks OK. Then there is either a firewall on NIC2 that blocks ICMP from LAN2 or the virtual network card on NIC2 is not configured correctly. I would try to reach other destinations from the server via LAn2.

Comment: But everything is default. I installed server 2008, installed the server roles. Configured dhcp, rras and ad. And that's it. It's a virtual environment, so how can it be configured wrong? I disabled the firewall, but still no go.

Comment: You could have set the virtual NIC2 to the same physical NIC as the NIC1. Or even worse have set NIC2 in NAT-mode than bridging mode.

Comment: This is wrong. A DHCP Discover broadcast is UDP not ICMP.